# cURL request for .ATOM feed issue

Tags: php, xml, curl, atom-feed

[This](https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom) is my XML format .ATOM feed. I am getting the following WARNINGS.

I am facing issues trying to extract the data from the ATOM URL and display it as a PHP code and save it to the DATABASE. I keep getting these errors...

I have tried using `loadfile`, `curl`, `vardump()` and nothing worked.

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /public_html/ecomcharts/beta/indexproducts.php on line 226
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom" in
>   /public_html/ecomcharts/beta/indexproducts.php on line 226 bool(false)
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error
>   : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /public_html/ecomcharts/beta/indexproducts.php on line 228
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():
>   https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom in
>   //ecomcharts/beta/indexproducts.php on line 228

I am not sure what is wrong. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    function download_page($path) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
        curl_close($ch);
        return $retValue;
    }

    $sXML = download_page('https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom');
    echo $sXML;
    $xml=var_dump(simplexml_load_file('https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom'));

    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement('https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom');

    foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry) {
        echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and failed? What are you seeing if you manually do the cURL request from a console? Please EDIT your question above with this information, so someone can be able to help you.

Comment: ok i edited it :)

Comment: Do you get an error if you manually try the cURL command from a console?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a SimpleXMLElement with the constructor, you pass in the contents of the file and not the file name, so in your case...

```
<?php
$url = 'https://colourpop.com/collections/all.atom';
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
);

$ch      = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$sXML = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( $sXML );

foreach ( $oXML->entry as $oEntry ) {
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

This also fixes the problems of trying to read HTTPS pages using curl (using the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFIER method)